# How to convert a multi record multiline JSON into single line per record JSON for AWS Athena?

Tags: python, sql, json, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I want to use a json file with AWS Athena, but Athena doesn't support multi line JSONs.

I have the following (one of the values is an XML)

```
{
  "id" : 10,
  "name" : "bob",
  "data" : "<some> \n <xml> \n <in here>"
},
{
  "id" : 20,
  "name" : "jane",
  "data" : "<other> \n <xml> \n <in here>"
}
```

And I need the following for Athena

```
{ "id" : 10, "name" : "bob", "data" : "<some> <xml> <in here>" },
{ "id" : 20, "name" : "jane", "data" : "<other> <xml> <in here>" }
```

I'm exporting the data from a DB2 using RazorSQL and trying to do some code to "flatten" it with Python, but had not succeeded yet.

Thank you!

Comment: This isn’t valid JSON syntax, nor as it stands is it meaningful Python syntax. Is this content in a file?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: The actual JSON file was more an array `[ { "prop": "value"}, { "prop" : "value"} ]` but it seems that Athena likes it only in the way shown on my example. I tried it and it works in Athena with that format, but don't take my word for it since I'm just learning it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing some quick and dirty stuff

```
import json
with open('data.json') as jfile:
    data = json.load(jfile)
    for d in data:
        print(json.dumps(d) + ',')
```

Which prints

```
{'id': 200, 'name': 'bob', 'data': '<other> \n <xml> \n <data>'},
{"id": 200, "name": "bob", "data": "<other> \n <xml> \n <data>"},
```

Just saved the output to another file :P

And it failed, because the file was too big, but hey.. was close!

Answer (score 0):

Use regex

```
import re
html = '''
{
  "id" : 10,
  "name" : "bob",
  "data" : "<some> \n <xml> \n <in here>"
},
{
  "id" : 20,
  "name" : "jane",
  "data" : "<other> \n <xml> \n <in here>"
}
'''


def replaceReg(html, regex, new):
    return re.sub(re.compile(regex), new, html)

html = replaceReg(html,' \n ',' ')
html = replaceReg(html,'{[\s]+','{ ')
html = replaceReg(html,'[\s]+}',' }')
html = replaceReg(html,',[\s]+',', ')
html = replaceReg(html,'}, ','\n')
print (html)
```

Result:

```
{ "id" : 10, "name" : "bob", "data" : "<some> <xml> <in here>" 
{ "id" : 20, "name" : "jane", "data" : "<other> <xml> <in here>" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to **replace** the end line feed characters(**\n**) while writing to another file :

```
s=''
with open('input.txt','r') as f_in, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:        
        s += line.replace('\n', '')
    f_out.write(s)
```

where input.txt has this data :

```
{
  "id" : 10,
  "name" : "bob",
  "data" : "<some> \n <xml> \n <in here>"
},
{
  "id" : 20,
  "name" : "jane",
  "data" : "<other> \n <xml> \n <in here>"
}
```